# What kind of changes happens in the picture when a Fourier transform picture is taken again? (2 times Fourier transform same image)

Tags: image, image-processing

What kind of changes happens in the picture when a Fourier transform picture is taken again? (2 times Fourier transform)
Anybody can show mathematically.

Comment: Did you try it out? What did you see?

Comment: I did not try, I am looking for an answer that shows me the way. Some of my friends are saying you will take same image.

Comment: If you try it out, you won't need to ask the question. It's pretty obvious when you try it!

Comment: @CrisLuengo thank you for your interest sir. But I need to make it with math. if you know to apply Fourier transform to an image can you show me